# Shelling EXE causes form to lose focus briefly, annoying flicker

Tags: winapi, vb6

I am trying to launch an external exe invisibly (one I created, I can modify it if need be) and then swap the interface into a picturebox seamlessly using setparent from my form. This works great with the exception of a brief focus/unfocus/focus issue that occurs in my form after running shell. I am passing in vbNormalNoFocus which doesn't seem to help much. The external exe I am launching is a standard exe with visibility set to false.

Can anyone recommend a solution or an entirely different approach?

```
Dim ConvertTwipsToPixelX As Long
Dim ConvertTwipsToPixelY As Long
Dim a As String

counter = counter + 1

'Launch external exe 
Pid = Shell(app.path & "\myexe.exe", vbNormalNoFocus)
'Get handle
mWnd = InstanceToWnd(Pid)

'Create container
Set pic = Me.Controls.Add("VB.Picturebox", "Picture" & counter)
pic.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

'Swap instance into new container
SetParent mWnd, pic.hwnd

ConvertTwipsToPixelX = Form1.ScaleWidth / Screen.TwipsPerPixelX
ConvertTwipsToPixelY = Form1.ScaleHeight / Screen.TwipsPerPixelY

'Move it
pic.Move 0, 800, Form1.ScaleWidth, Form1.ScaleHeight
Call SetWindowPos(mWnd, pic.hwnd, 0, 0, ConvertTwipsToPixelX, ConvertTwipsToPixelY, SWP_NOZORDER Or SWP_SHOWWINDOW)

'Make it visible
pic.Visible = True
```

Comment: could you try using `vbMinimizedNoFocus` in your `Shell()` call?

Comment: I tried that one too. I think I may need to subclass or something.

Comment: Why did you code the other exe to show itself when it starts? Also, SetParent for cross process hosting won't end well. Why don't you do it properly?

Comment: This is for a tabbed browser (similar to how Chrome creates a separate instance of chrome.exe for each tab). This actually works, each tab crashes independently of the main exe/interface (I'm using setparent for fullscreen mode and haven't had any problems with it there). After the user exits my main form I just iterate through all my handles and close them one by one.

Comment: Subclassing won't work across process boundaries.

Comment: Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship? Yes, it is. [It is also technically legal to juggle chainsaws](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx). Requirement: You have to control the code for all participating processes. Since you are using VB6 you are not in control of your host application. (Being in control in this context means: Controlling each and every message dispatch, including, but not limited to, the message loop.)

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw maybe a system wide hook? It seems like a simpler solution should be out there though.

Comment: @IInspectable it seems to work okay, with the exception of my focus problem (no other UI issues so far).

Comment: Systemwide hooks might work, although this is a sledgehammer to crack a nut scenario. Please tell me you are not developing this software for end users! BTW, did you develop the EXEs you are shelling out to? If you have control over these EXEs, there may be other ways of doing this.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw Yes, I wrote the exe I'm shelling out to. I've searched high and low and found the same question over and over again... I could not find a simple solution. I suppose underneath the hood this is a hackish/ugly approach but ultimately from the users perspective it simply works. If you know of a different approach or solution I'd be glad to explore any suggestions you may have.